# Symfony : These messages are not available for the given locale and cannot be found in the fallback locales

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to use symfony translations. Here is my translation.yml

```
framework:
    default_locale: 'en'
    translator:
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks: ['en']
```

I have created messages.en.yml in translations directory.

```
## YAML Template.
Home: Home
Admin: Admin
Dashboard: Dashboard
Vehicles: Vehicles
Id: Id
```

But when I try to use like this,

```
{% trans %}Dashboard{% endtrans %}
```

I get this error message,

> These messages are not available for the given locale and cannot be
>   found in the fallback locales. Add them to the translation catalogue
>   to avoid Symfony outputting untranslated contents.

Comment: Try messages.en.yaml instead of messages.en.yml.

Comment: sorry but still getting the same error

Comment: did you craete translations directory in project dir, or you created it under Recources directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A locale consists of 2 parts (language and country) combined with an underscore: eg. it_IT or en_EN

For example switzerland has 3 spoken languages:

- de_CH
- ch_CH
- fr_CH

The filenames of your translation-files should be like:

- messages.en_EN.yml
- messages.it_IT.yml
- ...

The translation-keys should be unique, dot-separated and equal in each single translation-file. First comes translation-key and after the colon comes the translated content.

```
# messages.it_IT.yml
navigation.home: Clicca per casa
navigation.help: Clicca per aiuto

# messages.en_EN.yml
navigation.home: Click for home
navigation.help: Click for help
```

Now you can use the navigation-keys in your application and a good IDE will help you by selecting them. When using different files for the different parts of your application, you have to address them in twig like:

```
{{ 'navigation.home'|trans({}, 'application') }}
{{ 'navigation.help'|trans({}, 'application') }}

<div class="error-message">
    The following error occured: {{ 'error.login'|trans({}, 'messages') }}
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but when I dump I get 'en' and when I try messages.it.yml it works perfectly. Anyway thanks and I'm upvoting you When I get the right

Answer (score 2):

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Clear your cache, if you craeted new translation file, you have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a work around. added messages.it.yml file and changed `fallbacks: ['it']` in  translation.yml

```
framework:
    default_locale: 'en'
    translator:
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks: ['it']
```

since I already added messages.en.yml changes showed with english bu I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: I edited my answer to make the function of the translation files more clear. When I read your answer correctly your problem still seems not to be solved. Now you have set "en" as default for all new sessions and when a translation-key is not found, then it should fallback to "it". So when the translations-key differ between your files you will get a real messed up result :-) Hope my additional explanations help you :-)