# Prestashop 1.7.5.1 Symfony Error: Missing translations while editing product in back office causing slow editing of products in back office

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

[image]

This screenshot has been taken in debug mode.
I have only 1 language en-US
I get errors of missing translations for all my categories, features, etc when trying to edit a product. The delay was 23 seconds, so I turned on debug mode to see the error.

Since I have only 1 language, it is not possible to have translations for these terms in the back office. With debug mode off, everything works smoothly, but extremely slow with very high MySQL usage.

The error clearly states:
"These messages are not available for the given locale and cannot be found in the fallback locales. Add them to the translation catalogue to avoid Symfony outputting untranslated contents."

Please explain how to avoid the same. and get the editing of products in Prestashop quick?

Comment: You have provided no code or locale information but I have found similar question so maybe it will help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony : These messages are not available for the given locale and cannot be found in the fallback locales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908930/symfony-these-messages-are-not-available-for-the-given-locale-and-cannot-be-fo)

Comment: I think my question is a little bit different. I have only 1 language - English. Why do I need to create translation files. The errors is being shown for simple terms seen in the dashboard and for product features. Kindly help.